# How to disable local file writes?

Tags: permissions, home, readonly

I maintain a shared public computer. Every user has their own directory in `/home`. We don't like to make `/home` a network mount because it takes a long time for new users to login, but we would like to set it so users can't write to their `/home` directories. We have network storage available to users that they should use instead, but we have no way to force them to use it.

Ideally I want to prevent them from writing data to the local machine at all, instead directing them to write to the storage server. If that's not possible, I'd at least like to limit their disk quota on the local machine so they can't consume all the space. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Consider that as a bug of the Application. Tell us more about the Application, and how you run it. You could run it with a different user (e.g. `nobody`)

Comment: Also, usual applications and usual users want legitimately to write into `/home/` so you don't want to disable it system-wide.

Comment: You use slave mounts for /home and you configure [disk quotas](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/)

Comment: How do I get access to the **public** computer? Do I need to provide my own HDD? How much are the cost?

Comment: Are the users' home directories in `/home` or in the network-mounted location (which is presumably mounted outside `/home`). If nobody's home directory is actually in `/home` then you can actually delete the whole directory if you want. There is nothing special about the name `/home`, it's just a conventional location for placing home directories. Alternatively, you can delete the entire local `/home` and mount the network file system on `/home`.

Comment: After your recent edit, it sounds like you simply want to set up `/home` as a network mount. There are **tons** of guides to doing this as it's a very common practice. Google 'linux network mount home directory' (substitute linux with your OS). If you have an issue, then we can help.

Comment: "every time new user check in their have to download /home/user's directory/ to ram from the network and it may take longer time to boot.". That's not how it works on Unix. It'll be an NFS (etc.) mount, and files will only be downloaded from the server when they're used. It doesn't work like it does on Windows, where the entire profile is downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create per directory limits by mounting filesystem image files on subdirectories in `/home`.  This won't disable `/home`, but it will solve your problem in so far as it will prevent people from writing more than a fixed amount.

A filesystem image file works like this:

1. Create an empty file of a fixed size, e.g. 100 MB:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/home/bob.img bs=1024 count=100000
   ```

   You don't have to use `/var/home` for these; it's a directory which otherwise would not exist.  *These files should be owned root and set mode 600* so that no one else can read them.  Make sure, obviously, that you have room to create a 100 MB file for every user, but keep in mind you will be able to eliminate everything in `/home` at the same time and free up that space.
2. Create a filesystem in the image:

   ```
   mke2fs -m 0 /var/home/bob.img
   ```

   This will warn you that `bob.img is not a block special device` -- proceed anyway.

   The first time you do this, presumably you want to copy in the user's existing home, so you'll have to mount it temporarily:

   ```
   mount /var/home/bob.img /mnt/tmp
   mv /home/bob/* /mnt/tmp
   mv /home/bob/.* /mnt/tmp
   ```

The last one will ask if you want to overwrite `.` and `..`.  **Don't.**  It's just for moving "hidden" dot files in the toplevel, which the first `mv` will have left behind.  You could also use a filebrowser or some other method to do the move.  `/home/bob` should now be empty, and you can move the mounted image there:

```
    umount /mnt/tmp
    mount /var/home/bob.img /home/bob
```

Voila, everything *seems* to be back the way it was -- except `/home/bob` is now an independent filesystem, and user `bob` won't be able to put more than 100 MB there. Also, because it is an existing image file, this space will be reserved for bob and won't get taken up with anything else.

You'll need a init service to mount all these at boot time; it could be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

for img in /var/home/*.img; do
    name=$(basename $img .img)
    mount $img "/home/$name"
done
```

They should be unmounted automatically when the system shuts down.  The data is as safe as it would be anywhere else.

Comment: Thank Goldilocks for your very clearly instructions. It was solve most of my problems. But to be completely clear the problem, Is there any solution to make the public computer become stateless at all time. I mean that after turn off / on, the computer become the same at the very first time where it come out from the computer department and having no data of any one

Comment: It's not impossible, although there are probably some things you do want to maintain, such as system logs.  But as long as you don't need to install or remove anything, most of the root filesystem can be used read-only.

Comment: Kindly give me more details about "the service to mount all these at the boot time". Do i have to write a Deamond or just use the bash shell.

Comment: It doesn't need to be complex.  I've added an example to the last paragraph which will work with the `/var/home/bob.img` -> `/home/bob` pattern.

Comment: In case i do not need to keep system log and still like to restore to the original state after turn on/off. All i have to do is use root privilege to change all the files to read only. Can it be like that?

Comment: Not having permanent logs is a pretty bad idea, but that's not impossible either; one way to do this is to make `/var/log` a tmpfs filesystem.  That's beyond the scope of this question though.  I wouldn't change the permissions on individual files, I'd just mount the fs read-only.  But again, as a warning, going down that road too far will make your life harder, not easier.

Comment: I have proposed a broader question on this topic.  Please searching for ' secure the content of hard disk'